# Do I need to add <build_depend> entries for pure Python packages?

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-kinetic, package.xml, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the *package.xml* file we specify dependencies that we need at compile time for our package, e.g., as `<build_depend>rospy</build_depend>`.

As my Python package contains only Python code, that is not really compiled, do I actually have dependencies at compile time?

Or would it be enough to specify runtime dependencies for [my example node](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29#rospy_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.Writing_the_Subscriber_Node)?

Example (derived from [this one](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage#ROS.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-catkin.2BAC8-CreatingPackage.Final_package.xml)):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>beginner_tutorials</name>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
  <description>The beginner_tutorials package</description>

  <maintainer email="you@yourdomain.tld">Your Name</maintainer>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <url type="website">http://wiki.ros.org/beginner_tutorials</url>
  <author email="you@yourdomain.tld">Jane Doe</author>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <exec_depend>rospy</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>

</package>
```

With a CMakeLists.txt, that I think, should go along these lines:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(beginner_tutorials)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rospy
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package()

install(PROGRAMS
  scripts/listener.py
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331164/do-i-need-to-add-%3Cbuild_depend%3E-entries-for-pure-python-packages?/) by [moooeeeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/27965/moooeeeep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 194 on 2019-08-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-08-20**:
Please share your CMakeLists.txt which will allow to determine if the specified dependencies are sufficient. On a first look it should be good as is.

**Comment by [moooeeeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/27965/moooeeeep/) on 2019-08-20**:
@DirkThomas I made up a *CMakeLists.txt*, but I'm again not sure, whether I actually need to define the `REQUIRED COMPONENTS` for catkin here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't need the `REQUIRED COMPONENTS rospy std_msgs` in the `find_package(catkin)`.

With those removed the stated dependencies (`exec_depend` on `rospy` and `std_msgs` without the need for `build_depend`) are sufficient.

Side note: you want to use `catkin_install_python(...)` instead of `install(...)` for your Python scripts since it will make sure to rewrite the shebang line of the script to the selected Python interpreter. The custom function takes the same arguments so you only need to change the function name.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1